# Android L devices not sending notification card to Android Wear SmartWatch

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop, wear-os

I'm trying to send a notification to an Android Wear SmartWatch when a button is clicked. It's working in all devices I have tested, except for the ones with Android L. Does anyone have any idea about what may be the problem? I have even paired the devices with an Android Wear SmartWatch emulator, but, again, it does not work with Android L devices.

Below is my button:

```
// the button click listener
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new MyNotification(getApplicationContext()).sendNotification();
            }
});
```

And MyNotification class:

```
public class MyNotification {

    private static final AtomicInteger ID_COUNT = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private int mNotificationID;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyNotification(Context context) {
        mNotificationID = ID_COUNT.incrementAndGet();
        mContext = context;
    }

    private void sendNotification() {
        final Intent viewIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        final PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, viewIntent, 0);

        final Bitmap bgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        final NotificationCompat.Action action =
                new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Connect",
                        pendingIntent).build();

        wearableExtender =
                new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                        .addAction(action)
                        .setBackground(bgBitmap);

        final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                        .setContentTitle("Title")
                        .setContentText("Text")
                        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
                        .setGroup(NOTIFICATION_GROUP)
                        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                        .setDefaults(android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                        .extend(wearableExtender);

        final NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext);

        notificationManager.notify(mNotificationID, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The problem was that I was not setting the small icon of the builder.
So, my code was supposed to be as follows:

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                            .setContentTitle("Title")
                            .setContentText("Text")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.someIcon)
                            .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
                            .setGroup(NOTIFICATION_GROUP)
                            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                            .setDefaults(android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                            .extend(wearableExtender);
```

I don't know why, but it works well on Android KitKat devices, but not on Android Lollipop.

Comment: Are you talking about Android Wear or Smartwatch (by Sony, not running Android Wear)?

Comment: @Tajchert, Android Wear.